# No surefire plugin in my pom - How does it show surefire output?

Tags: java, maven, testing, plugins, testng

I do not have surefire plug-in entry in my pom. But I get surefure plug-in error, when I run with command:

```
 mvn test -Dtest=TEstClass
```

Error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-
 test) on project my-projection: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore 
 this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [super pom](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) for a project includes the surefire plugin. If you run `mvn help:effective-pom` it will show you the pom which you are in effect using whenever you invoke maven in your project, including everything you inherit from parent pom files, and you'll see that it includes the surefire plugin.

Comment: Oh, man. This super POM doesn't include any mentioning of surefire plugin.

Comment: Just opened super pom of maven 3.6.3 - it does not contain maven-surefire-plugin. But the plugin is present in my effective pom.

Comment: These are added as the default plugins to execute for each lifecycle phase, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72319326/18699445